# Issues while converting utf-8 to arabic

Tags: java

Arabic Characters are coming in XML request without setting any character set in request header. in text file, characters are going correctly. but if we insert into oracle table, its going as Øº.Ø¨ (Ø´Ù?Ø±)

1. manual insertion in table is going fine.
2. tried conversion with different type codes: `System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(Value, "ISO-8859-9"));` used `ByteBuffer ByteArrayInputStream`.
3. one more thing is noticed:
   if we set charset=UTF-8 in header than all is going fine and if we print encoded string it prints as: utf-8 in header:  `50+%D8%BA.%D8%A8+%28%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1%29`
   and if we didn't set the charset in header, then string prints as: `50+%C3%98%C2%BA.%C3%98%C2%A8+%28%C3%98%C2%B4%C3%99%C2%87%C3%98%C2%B1%29`

and second string is going fine in text file.

please someone suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Do not just think its not going fine in DB change all the fonts and see in the Oracle DB. The Arabic characters is fine but sometimes are not supported by the current font you have selected in SQL developer

Comment: even I do not touch the preference settings of Oracle two different XMLs containing arabic characters: first line: <Description>50 Øº.Ø¨ (Ø´ÙØ±)</Description> and second line: 
<Description>50 غ.ب (شهر)</Description>